# How can i write conditional statement inside html page in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In Ionic , I am trying to write the same code using ionic list.
Below is my html template for the reference.

```
    <ion-view>
    <ion-content>
    <ion-list class="product_father"> 
    <ion-item  class="back_style span_txt_color" ng-repeat="playorderslist in playorderslists"> 
        <span class="span_txt_color"><b>REFERENCE:</b> 
           {{playorderslist.reference}} <span class="span_txt_color2" > 
           {{playorderslist.date_add}}</span> <br>
           <br/>{{playorderslist.payment}}<br>
      <span class="span_txt_color1" style="background-color: 
          {{playorderslist.order_state_color}}; width:100%">{{playorderslist.order_state}}</span><BR><br>
    <b>TOTAL PRICE:</b>{{playorderslist.total_paid}} 
  // i want to put here my condition  
    <a  class="bc_a_color" target="_blank" href="https://test.com/pdfinvoicemobile?id_order={{playorderslist.id_orders}}">PDF</a> 
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div id="load_html" >
    </div>
    <div id="load_html_browse">
      <div class="same_footer"></div>
    </ion-content>

    </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use condition statement like this

```
<a *ngIf="Yourcondition" class="bc_a_color" target="_blank" href="https://test.com/pdfinvoicemobile?id_order={{playorderslist.id_orders}}">PDF</a>
```